# How to change the name of a color in Adobe Acrobat DC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, color, adobe-acrobat

I want to change the name of a color in my PDF file. Is this possible in Adobe Acrobat DC?

[image: This is the colors name i want to change]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit spot color name in inDesign or Illustrator before you make the pdf. But I'm afraid you can't in Acrobat.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Acrobat Pro using a Preflight Fixup.

There is a one already created called "Map spot color with specified name and color value", which you can modify to suit.

[image: Preflight index]

[image: Preflight Edit]